# fabricjs: export with custom canvas attributes

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

With `canvas.toJSON();` I cannot export the custom canvas attributes.

I have to use prototype of canvas. But I don't know how to build a prototype structure.

Existing (allowed) data:

```
var clipFath = this.clipPath, data = {
         version: fabric.version,
         objects: this._toObjects (methodName, propertiesToInclude),
};
```

I need it this way:

```
var clipFath = this.clipPath, data = {
         version: fabric.version,
         objects: this._toObjects (methodName, propertiesToInclude),
         custom_settings_json: this.custom_settings /* <-- */
};
```

Original source [line 7698](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line7698):

In the following example, I can add custom settings to fabric objects. I need a similar structure for canvas. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425316/6320082)

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
  return function (propertiesToInclude) {
      propertiesToInclude = (propertiesToInclude || []).concat(
        ['custom_attr_1','custom_attr_2'] /* <- */
      );
      return toObject.apply(this, [propertiesToInclude]);
  };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

I tried this to set for canvas, as below

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var custom = {
    "data1": 1,
    "data2": 2
}
canvas.custom_settings_json = custom;
var json_data = canvas.toJSON();
console.log(json_data);

// console log:
{
  "version":"2.4.1",
  "objects":[{.....}],
  "custom_settings_json": {
        "data1": 1,
        "data2": 2
  }
}
```

But I am getting this result without `custom_settings_json` in `toJSON` output.

```
// console log:
{
  "version":"2.4.1",
  "objects":[{.....}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend `_toObjectMethod` method from `fabric.StaticCanvas`.

I made a exemple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/sLaz4kp9/8/).
Open the console and you will see the json from `toJSON` method with custom parameters data1,data2,data3.

```js
//rewrite core
fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype._toObjectMethod = (function(toObjectMethod) {
  return function(propertiesToInclude) {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObjectMethod.call(this, "toDatalessObject", propertiesToInclude), {
      data1: this.data1,
      data2: this.data2,
      data3: this.data3,
    });
  };
})(fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype._toObjectMethod);
//end

var myCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('my-canvas');
myCanvas.data1 = 1;
myCanvas.data2 = 2;
myCanvas.data3 = 4;
console.log(myCanvas.toJSON(['test']));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js'></script>

<canvas id="my-canvas" width="550" height="550"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Your `_toObjectMethod` includes `toObject` of all objects of canvas. [check](https://jsfiddle.net/sLaz4kp9/10/). as you are overriding `_toObjectMethod` there is two parameter `('toObject', propertiesToInclude)` or `_toObjectMethod('toDatalessObject', propertiesToInclude)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `toJSON` of canvas. As besically you need to add properties after getting the canvas data as json, just extend with your custom property after.

***DEMO***

```js
fabric.Canvas.prototype.toJSON = (function(toJSON) {
  return function(propertiesToInclude) {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toJSON.call(this,propertiesToInclude), {
      custom_settings_json: this.custom_settings_json
    });
  }
})(fabric.Canvas.prototype.toJSON);

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  "custom_settings_json": {
    "data1": 1,
    "data2": 2
  }
});

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  radius: 50
}))

console.log(canvas.toJSON())
```

```css
canvas{
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's not totaly correct. you need to add the parameter from toJSON method.

Comment: @MariusTurcu, sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: Please check the documentation.           http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html. toJSON method has one parameter used for any object properties that you might want to additionally include in the output

Comment: @Durga Your answer is correct. I respect the your labor. But the answer I have marked as correct is more appropriate to my code. Thank you, good person.