# FabricJS: Failed to execute 'drawImage' when using an Image subclass

Tags: javascript, json, image, fabricjs, subclass

for a project I need adding images of various types to canvas, saving to JSON and loading again. The different types does not have any specific properties, I only need the type to be different.

I have created a new class based on fabric.Image like this:

```
fabric.Icon = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
      type: "icon",
      initialize: function (element, options) {
        this.callSuper("initialize", element, options);
      },
      _render: function (ctx) {
        this.callSuper("_render", ctx);
      },
    });
    fabric.Icon.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
      return fabric.Object._fromObject("Icon", object, callback);
    };
```

After this I add new object of this new type using a SVG image:

```
let newImage = new Image();    //HTML Image type, not FabricJS
newImage.onload = () => {
   let icon = new fabric.Icon(newImage);   //my subclass of fabric.Image class
   this.canvas.add(icon);
};
newImage.src = "image.svg";
```

When I export the canvas into JSON with

```
let savedJSON = canvas.toJSON()
```

and load it back with

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(savedJSON, function () {
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

When I use standard fabric.Image class, everything works correctly. Should I override some other method in my subclass? Or should I differentiate the various Image types in some another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not really a solution to this problem, but I found the correct way to differentiate between objects which persists within saving and loading - setting the custom property on the Object.prototype by overriding its toObject method like here:
[Fabric js extending toObject with custom properties, loses default ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286547/fabric-js-extending-toobject-with-custom-properties-loses-default-ones)
Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The fabric Image class has a slightly more complicated restore mechanism, since it wants an image element in the constructor, that is not serializable.

this is how it is implemented in fabricJS:

```js
  /**
   * Creates an instance of fabric.Image from its object representation
   * @static
   * @param {Object} object Object to create an instance from
   * @param {Function} callback Callback to invoke when an image instance is created
   */
  fabric.Image.fromObject = function(_object, callback) {
    var object = fabric.util.object.clone(_object);
    fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function(img, isError) {
      if (isError) {
        callback && callback(null, true);
        return;
      }
      fabric.Image.prototype._initFilters.call(object, object.filters, function(filters) {
        object.filters = filters || [];
        fabric.Image.prototype._initFilters.call(object, [object.resizeFilter], function(resizeFilters) {
          object.resizeFilter = resizeFilters[0];
          fabric.util.enlivenObjects([object.clipPath], function(enlivedProps) {
            object.clipPath = enlivedProps[0];
            var image = new fabric.Image(img, object);
            callback(image, false);
          });
        });
      });
    }, null, object.crossOrigin);
  };
```

I'm afraid you have to copy it and swap the fabric.Image with fabric.Icon

Comment: Thanks for the reply, eventually I do not need to do this as I found the correct way to differentiate among objects, using another custom property.